# Is it possible to have AMPscript fetch the HTML of an email (prior to send) and automatically place it in an HTML content block?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I am wondering if I have an email, already built out with content in place, if I would be able to have AMPscript automatically pull the HTML of the email into a separate HTML block?

I then would like to use the reference function to grab the HTML content block and place it into a landing page.

The end goal being: if I, for example, change the text in my email, the AMPscipt updates the HTML content block -- which because I am using a reference block -- will automatically update the landing page (without having to republish the landing page).

The landing page in this scenario would result in an exact duplicate of the drafted email - which would auto-update as needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Usually you only change certain areas of an email. So in my opinion it would only be necessary to "replicate" certain content blocks. If this applies you could create those blocks in the email and save them to content builder for reference in your landing page. When you update the blocks in the email you only need to save the updates to have a current version in your landing page.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you are trying to build a custom View as Web Page solution? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_view_email_as_web_page_link_in_html_paste_emails.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Stephan, that unfortunately doesn't work for my use case as my organization has multiple contributors that need to add in content via the content builder only. Lukas, essentially yes, but I send 20+ different newsletters every week, sending emails to myself in that volume would be tedious to get the links.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but you may be able to do what you're describing using HTTPGet(view_email_url). I currently post the entire HTML of an email into a field in a data extension within an InsertDE() function. You might be able to use that combo of functions to declare a variable and then use it elsewhere.